# Beta version nugets not supported by UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Am trying to make [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) compatible with UWP and running into some issues. I've made it target the `dotnet` TFM, although unlike some other projects (EF7), Npgsql depends on nugets which only have beta versions on nuget.org (e.g. [System.Threading.Thread](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Thread/)), or for which only the beta version has my required types (e.g. [System.Net.NetworkInformation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.NetworkInformation) 4.0.0 doesn't have `PhysicalAddress`, but 4.1.0-beta-23225 does).

When trying to build a UWP app which depends on Npgsql, I get the following build error for all beta dependencies of Npgsql:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.1.0-beta-23225 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.NetworkInformation on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86
```

Are some packages simply not yet ready to be used in a UWP app, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, many packages are not ready to be used in UWP app, so you must wait for new versions of this packages.

Comment: This means all what I need is .NET standard 2? do you recon it'd work with the current preview?